# ThinkPad T490 maximum screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T490 with Intel UHD Graphics 620 integrated video card which is running Ubuntu 18.04.

For some reason the maximum resolution I can set in Ubuntu's setting is 1366x768. Obviously for a 14" screen this is awful. I know I can register a custom resolution using xrandr, and set it (it partially works, but it's hard to read text from the screen - there is no anti-aliasing (or how it's called) and it simply looks bad). 
I also have Dell 7490 with the same video card, and the same Ubuntu version. And there Ubuntu can detect the maximum screen resolution.

Why Ubuntu doesn't see thinkpad's maximum screen resolution?

Update: laptop's model name is 20N2CTO1WW, and it supports FHD screen resolution.

Comment: I think the bottleneck is the resolution of the monitor screen, the number of pixels. If you force a higher resolution, the screen cannot display it, but must use some kind of mathematics (interpolation) to decide what intensity and colour to send it each pixel.

Comment: Nope, according to the specs T490 supports fhd resolution.

Comment: T490 can support FHD resolution, but it is possible to purchase a T490 with a 1366x768 TN display (220 nits). It is possible your T490 simply does not have a FHD screen.

Comment: Some of the T490 computers support 1920x1080, some of them only 1366x768. See [this link](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T490/ThinkPad_T490_Spec.PDF)

Comment: I am 100% sure that it supports 1920x1080, as I can register a custom resolution with xrandr and set it. When it's set I clearly can see pixels.

Comment: My bad... I have a TN display, which means that it's a model with 1366x768 :(